# Select Fabric First Then Color?

Tags: attributes, attribute-set

How can I set up attributes that if i pick this fabric, I get these color options, or if I select that fabric, I get a second list of colors?

Comment: From what I know, it's not possible out of the box in Magento.

Comment: Thanks.  I was afraid of that.  Any custom solutions?

Comment: Would you not just create 2 attribute sets?  Are there only 2 attribute sets of colors or are there more like 10 various options?

Comment: I was creating two sets of attribute colors, but I only want the color options to show for the type of fabric customer choses.

Comment: You will probably have to go into your product page in a theme and do this via .phtml (depending on version) or XML.  What version are you using?

Comment: Currently we are on 1.7 but we are looking to upgrade to 2.1 in a few weeks

Comment: "upgrading" from 1.7 to 2.1? good luck to you sir