# First select color, then

Tags: magento-1.9, bundled-product, color-swatches

I have seen a similar question but no answer, so trying again. ([Select Fabric First Then Color?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124162/select-fabric-first-then-color))

In our shop, we have a product in different colors (bright and dark) with their own SKU. I have setup 1 bundle product with a bright board and 3 bright hangers, so far so good, but I would actually like the customers to be able to choose bright or dark in the beginning.
http://roonrahn.dev.magepartner.net/produkter/moodboard-funktionelle-mobler/moodboard-1x6-eg-kit

If they choose bright board, they should only be shown bright hangers, and if they choose dark board, they should only be shown dark hangers... makes sense?

I hope you can help me find a solution on this :)

Answer (score 1):

for your requirement you have to create configurable product with multiple configurable attribute.

You can just google it, you  will get very good tutorial for how to create configurable products in magento.

So set the configurable sort order so on the first attribute selection rest of available options were fill in the next dropdown.

Comment: hmm... I'm not sure, what you are saying is the correct answer to this questions.

I have setup a new product, maybe that will clarify what I mean, or maybe you are aboslutely right, and can better tell me, what I do wrong.

http://roonrahn.dev.magepartner.net/produkter/moodboard-funktionelle-mobler/moodboard-1x6-eg-kit-99

I don't want to just select **color:black** **_size: xxl_**...

I want to select black collection... t-shirt, jeans, hat...

Comment: when you say "So set the configurable sort order so on the first attribute selection rest of available options were fill in the next dropdown." you mean, I should add "t-shirt, jeans, hat" as attribute options? (see comment above)

Comment: @Zyberchief no bro every attribute has sort order feild in set that value as per your req

Comment: Have you tried going to http://roonrahn.dev.magepartner.net/produkter/moodboard-funktionelle-mobler/moodboard-1x6-eg-kit-99 ?

It is the same as http://roonrahn.dev.magepartner.net/produkter/moodboard-funktionelle-mobler/moodboard-1x6-kit
But with the functionality to select what hanger, you want... I wouldn't know how to set this up in a configurabel product... 
**attribute1: standard-hanger / glasses-hanger / guitar-hanger** ?

If the customers can buy 3 hangers with the board, we need to create 3 attributes called _hanger1_ / _hanger2_ / _hanger3_  ??

I'm confused..